# Cucumber table + find("table tr:eq(x)") not working right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have this cucumber task:

```
Then I should see following posting modes
        | row | day  | hour | minute | location | category |
        | 1   | 1    | 7    | 0      | 29       | 6        |
        | 2   | 2    | 8    | 5      | 27       | 7        |
        | 3   | 3    | 9    | 10     | 28       | 18       |
        | 4   | 4    | 15   | 15     | 29       | 18       |
        | 5   | 5    | 17   | 20     | 27       | 7        |
        | 6   | 6    | 20   | 30     | 28       | 6        |
        | 6   | 0    | 22   | 50     | 29       | 7        |
```

And behind it there is this description:

```
Then /^I should see following posting modes$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |posting|
      within("#itemPosting .attributeContainer table tbody tr:eq(#{posting[:row]})") do
            find("#item_posting_day").value.should == posting[:day]
            find("#item_posting_hour").value.should == posting[:hour]
            find("#item_posting_minute").value.should == posting[:minute]
            find("#item_posting_location").value.should == posting[:location]
            find("#item_posting_category").value.should == posting[:category]
      end
  end  
end
```

So this part:

```
tr:eq(#{posting[:row]})
```

doesn't work(it goes to next step, and then gives an error that #item_posting_day is not found.)

But if I do this instead:

```
tr:eq(4)
```

It works (finds the #item_posting_day field, gets its value, and then gives an error saying that value is not what is expected to be, but that's ok).

So I don't understand what's the problem with using this syntax:

```
tr:eq(#{posting[:row]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [`hashes`](http://rubydoc.info/github/cucumber/cucumber/Cucumber/Ast/Table#hashes-instance_method) converts column headers to strings, not symbols. Try to use `'row'` instead of `:row`